# JSONarray separation to lists in android

Tags: android, arrays

I have the following JSONarray and I need to have the output like below. Help please.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Mandal": "Rambilli",
        "Village": "Chatametta"
    },
    {
        "Mandal": "Anakapalle",
        "Village": "Valluru"
    },
    {
        "Mandal": "Anakapalle",
        "Village": "Venkupalem"
    },
    {
        "Mandal": "Rambilli",
        "Village": "Chebrolu Konda"
    },
    {
        "Mandal": "Anakapalle",
        "Village": "Vetajangalapalem"
    },
    {
        "Mandal": "Anakapalle",
        "Village": "Vooderu"
    }
]
}
```

The out put needs to be two lists with names of Mandal

```
List<String> Rambilli to contain [Chatametta, Chebrolu Konda]
List Anakapalle to contain [Valluru, Venkupalem, Vetajangalapalem, Vooderu]
```

The major roadblock I'm facing is how to put the name of the mandal to the output list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hard coded every thing but Try:

```
    List<String> listOfRambilli = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> listOfAnakapalle = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray dataArray =  jsonData.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objectInsideDataArray = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String village = objectInsideDataArray.getString("Village");
            String mandal = objectInsideDataArray.getString("Mandal");

            if (mandal.equals("Rambilli"))
               listOfRambilli.add(village);

            else if (mandal.equals("Anakapalle"))
                listOfAnakapalle.add(village);
            else
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "" + listOfAnakapalle);
        Log.d("TAG", "" + listOfRambilli);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It works - but how to get the list name picked up from the array. Otherwise, I need to get list of all "mandals" and declare these lists.  Also what does the Log.d does? I have replaced it with AlertDialog

Comment: I'm choosing this as answer as it is easy to comprehend. I have got all the Mandals in a list - Mandalslist - now I need to investigate on how to create a String[] List for each of the item of the Mandalslist

Comment: The Log.d will enable you to debug your app, For Example, in our case, it will output both the list on the log console. the 'd' stand for 'debug', there is a couple of option also, like 'info', 'error'. You should start using them because they very help full for finding a 'Bug' in your code without actually setting **breakpoint**. You will find the 'Logcat' at bottom of android studio.

Comment: @sriram I don't get your seconde question tho.

Comment: Thank you. The second question is for each of the elements in the Mandallist, I would like to create another list with the same name as of the element. In otherwords, how to create a list with elements from another list android

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
ArrayList<String> rambilliList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> anakapalleList = new ArrayList<>();

 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject listJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if(listJsonObject.getString("Mandal").equals("Rambilli")){
    rambilliList.add(listJsonObject.getString("Village"));
    } else if(listJsonObject.getString("Mandal").equals("Anakapalle")) {
    anakapalleList.add(listJsonObject.getString("Village"));
    }
        }
   System.out.println("Rambilli contains" + rambilliList)
   System.out.println("Anakapalle contains" + anakapalleList)
```

Comment: Thank you. This also worked - but my question also has this part:  how to get the list name picked up from the array. Otherwise, I need to get list of all "mandals" and declare these lists.

Comment: If u want to do this means, is it possible to change ur array structure?

Comment: what changes I need to do the array structure? Finally I need to have list of "mandals" and lists of villages for each mandal with mandal name

Comment: @SriramNadiminti check this structure 

{
  "data": [
    {
      "Mandal": "Rambilli",
      "Rambilli": [
        {
          "Village": "Chatametta"
        },
        {
          "Village": "Chebrolu Konda"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Mandal": "Anakapalle",
      "Anakapalle": [
        {
          "Village": "Valluru"
        },
        {
          "Village": "Venkupalem"
        },
        {
          "Village": "Vetajangalapalem"
        },
        {
          "Village": "Vooderu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I'm getting the data from GoogleSheets with two columns and sending the data as JSON array. The suggested structure - requires lot of work as I'm using the data populating from a Form.